# binding not working with a property assigned from another Task

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, binding

Someone can quickly show me why my DataGrid bound to VesselCollection displays nothing. ReferentialVesselViewModel class  is the DataContext of ReferentialVesselView view (below the XAML). ItemsSource of the DataGrid is VesselCollection which is a ObservableCollection.

```
 public class ReferentialVesselViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ReferentialVesselViewModel()
        {
           Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {

                        VesselEntities = ServiceProxy.Load<VesselProxy, IEnumerable<Vessel>>(proxy => proxy.GetVesselTable());

                        foreach (var vessel in VesselEntities)
                            VesselCollection.Add(new ReferentialVesselLineViewModel(vessel));
                    })));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ReferentialVesselLineViewModel> VesselCollection { get; private set; }
    }
```

Xaml side here is the code

```
<UserControl  
    x:Class="MyCompany.Referential.ReferentialVesselView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyCompany.ViewModel"
    >

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:ReferentialVesselViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" Margin="5" Padding="10"  Background="White">
        <DataGrid 
                ItemsSource="{Binding VesselCollection, Mode=OneWay}" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CanUserAddRows="False" 
                CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vessel Code" Binding="{Binding VesselCode}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vessel Name" Binding="{Binding VesselName}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

and finally this is the class that expose properties like VesslName, VesselCode, etc..

```
public class ReferentialVesselLineViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Vessel vessel;

        public ReferentialVesselLineViewModel(Vessel vessel)
        {
            this.vessel = vessel;
        }

        public String VesselName
        {
            get { return vessel.Name; }
            set
            {
                if(vessel.Name != value)
                {
                    vessel.Name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("VesselName");
                }
            }
        }

        public String VesselCode
        {
            get { return vessel.Code; }
            set
            {
                if(vessel.Code != value)
                {
                    vessel.Code = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("VesselCode");
                }
            }
        }

        //...etc

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you set the source object of the VesselCollection binding (e.g. by setting a DataContext)? Probably also show the declarations of VesselCollection and ReferentialVesselLineViewModel.

Comment: <UserControl  
    x:Class="MyCompany.Referential.ReferentialVesselView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 >
 
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:ReferentialVesselViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" Margin="5" Padding="10"  Background="White">
  <DataGrid 
     ItemsSource="{Binding VesselCollection}"  >
  </DataGrid>
    </Border>

</UserControl>

Comment: public class ReferentialVesselViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ReferentialVesselViewModel()
        {
     //.....
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ReferentialVesselLineViewModel> VesselCollection { get; private set; }
 }

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Still missing the declaration of ReferentialVesselLineViewModel (just to be sure that VesselCode and VesselName are actually public properties). Did you put a breakpoint at the line `VesselCollection.Add(...)` to make sure that there really is some data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in fact, I should raise the NotifyPropertyChanged  event as soon as the collection is filled.

```
    public class ReferentialVesselViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            public ReferentialVesselViewModel()
            {
               Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {

                            VesselEntities = ServiceProxy.Load<VesselProxy, IEnumerable<Vessel>>(proxy => proxy.GetVesselTable());

                            foreach (var vessel in VesselEntities)
                                VesselCollection.Add(new ReferentialVesselLineViewModel(vessel));
 RaisePropertyChanged(() => VesselCollection);
                        })));
            }

                public ObservableCollection<ReferentialVesselLineViewModel> VesselCollection { get; private set; }
            }
```